# gluLookAt in reshape function

Tags: c++, glut

This is how my reshape func looks like

```
`void Reshape(int w, int h)
{
     const float ar = (float)w/(float)h;
     glViewport(0,0,w,h);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();              
     gluPerspective(20.0, ar, 1.0, 60.0); // fovy, aspect ratio, zNear, zFar
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
     glLoadIdentity();          
     gluLookAt(7,7,7,0,-1,0,0,1,0);
}`
```

When I rotate my view and then resize the window the camera comes back to position set in gluLookAt. What should I change, when I want to camera stay in rotated place after resize?

Comment: remove gluLookAt from Reshape ?

Comment: but then where put it?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have another glu look at in display. So you are. just wiping this in the next frame after reshape.

Anyway you are better just saving the window size in `int w, h;` and then have glulookat in the display or update func. Or infact you can leave the viewport call there.

I would recommend looking at GLFW rather than GLUT when you get this fixed.

Comment: If I have glulookat in displayfunc I can't rotate the camera then.

Comment: I must have one glulookat in reshape to set the view at start - and it resets my view every window resize

Comment: -1 No, you are wrong. Why the heck would resize be the only thing to move the camera. Not want to move it after pressing a key or moving the mouse?

Comment: Maybe my english is bad and you don't understood me. I rotate my camera using left and right key. So i have cone - rotate - and it's upside down. Then I resize my window and after this camera comes back to first place (cause resize calls reshape and then glulookat)

Answer (score 0):

> If I have glulookat in displayfunc I can't rotate the camera then.

Says who?
I'm not willing to disclose the code for the "class Camera" used in the folloiwing snippet, but the semantics should be quite clear.

```cpp
void reshape(int w, int h) {
    g_width = w; g_height = h;
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    ::glutPostRedisplay();
} 


void display(void) {
    /* 
       ...
    */    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    /* 
       ...
    */    
    gluPerspective(60.0, g_width/g_height, 0.1, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0);

    real* polar = &(Camera::get_instance()->polar[0]);

    gluLookAt(polar[0]*cos(polar[2])*sin(-polar[1]), 
              polar[0]*cos(polar[1]),
              polar[0]*sin(-polar[2])*sin(-polar[1]), 
              0,0,0, // look_at
              0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    /* 
        building the scene 
        [...] 
    */
}
```

g_width and g_height are vars at module scope.

Comment: Why do you think I post a snippet where exactly that is done.

Comment: My last comment was directed at a comment of the OP which has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `glLoadIdentity() + gluLookAt(...)` as used in yor reshape function completely overwrites your current modelview matrix - if you applied any rotations previously using `glRotate`, they will be gone, there's no way around that.

one possible quick-fix to your problem: don't just call `glRotate` when the left / right key is pressed; instead, store the total amount of rotation in some variable, and call `glRotate` after `gluLookAt` in the resize function as well.

however, if you're going to add more camera interactions to your code after that, keeping the camera matrices correct might become cumbersome; you'll end up with `glRotate / glTranslate / glScale` all over the place. I would instead advise you to use variables for all relevant values, like camera position, view vector etc. and calculate the camera matrices once per frame by calling `gluLookAt` as well as `gluPerspective` right before you draw anything - it's much easier to keep an overview that way.